# How do cfcache and cflocation work together?

Tags: coldfusion

I was wondering if placing a cfcache tag on a page with a cflocation did anything?

ex. If I have index.cfm and at the top I have a cfcache and then depending on some logic I might cflocation to bob.cfm, does this get cached?

Comment: Test and find out - but my understanding is that it is _only what is added to the buffer_ (i.e. content) that is cached.

Comment: Yeah, my tests seem to indicate that, but I found it strange that the question doesn't seem to be anywhere I could find.

Comment: Not a question that is often asked. caching tags are de facto used for content, so logic is not typically in play.

Comment: Indeed, however the cfcache tag was originally meant to cache a request and only later added the ability to cache pieces of content. It wouldn't be too far a stretch to imagine that it remembers cflocations.

Comment: Yeah - fair point.